# Track usage of Javascript on third party site

Tags: php, javascript

I have a snippet of javascript that I allow people to use as a way to display content from my site as a daily reminder/quote widget using. The data itself is from a php source i.e. code is written in php but displayed to third party sites by embedding a snippet of javascript.

I want to be able to accurately track how many unique websites are using my script to display the daily quote.

I can check awstats etc for number of hits to the page but that isn't the most accurate way of doing it.

I don't want to implement a mandatory registration before I have them use it as a I feel it will deter users from using it.

I dont want to create webservices (REST/Soap etc) either as that creates an obstacle for the users to implement on their side so leaving it as an embed works best at the moment.

I can't seem to find a solution, what are my options if any?

Comment: What's not accurate in checking the hits ? If you include a timestamp in the URL (ie you ensure the page isn't cached) it will be perfectly accurate.

Comment: You cannot track what people do with your code once it is out -- it is easy to modify and/or reverse engineer. You can only track access to your server. That being said, many online services use "api keys" to track usage, and offer the JS API code only as a convenience.

Comment: @dystroy perhaps you can tell me how I can find the unique number of websites that use the script via awstats?

Comment: why not track the referrer in php? `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` See [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php)